# Wait for client to enter name before broadcasting the server message

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

From GameServer.java:

```java
 while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PlayerThread playerThread = new PlayerThread(clientSocket, this);
            playerThreads.add(playerThread);
            playerThread.start();
            if (playerThreads.size() == maxPlayers) {
                broadcast("All players have joined! Let the game begin!", null);
            }
        }
```

From PlayerThread.java:

```java
 @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("What's your name? ");
            String userName = in.readLine();
            Player player = new Player(userName);
            gameServer.addPlayer(p);
            String clientMove;
            while ((clientMove = in.readLine()) != null) {
                gameServer.makeMove(player, clientMove);
                gameServer.broadcast(p.getName() + " made the move:  " + clientMove, this);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Starting the server:

[image]

Client1 at the end:

[image]

Client2 at the end:

[image]

How do I wait for the last client (here, client2) to enter their name before broadcasting the message?

Here's the broadcast function:

```java
public void broadcast(String message, PlayerThread excluded) {
        for (PlayerThread p : playerThreads) {
            if (p != excluded)
                p.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CountDownLatch`:

```
private CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(maxPlayers);
```

So, after `playerThreads.size() == maxPlayers` reached, call `await`:

```
    if (playerThreads.size() == maxPlayers) {
        countDownLatch.await();
        broadcast("All players have joined! Let the game begin!", null);
    }
```

You need to pass this `CountDownLatch` to every `PlayThread`, and after `username` is read, call `CountDownLatch#countDown`:

```
    public PlayerThread(Socket socket, GameServer gameServer, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) throws IOException {
            downLatch = countDownLatch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("What's your name? ");
                String userName = in.readLine();
                downLatch.countDown();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```